# Using GStreamer to connect to a PulseAudio stream

Tags: linux, gstreamer, pulseaudio

I'm trying to write a program that uses GStreamer to connect to PulseAudio as a source so that I can intercept any audio that's being played. I have no need to play it back so my assumption is that my pipeline only needs a source and demuxer, I'm not sure of the latter though. The hello world example that I'm working off of is [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-helloworld.html), except that instead of using "filesrc" I'm using "pulsesrc".

Is there a good example that shows this out there already and I haven't found the right combination of terms to make Google give it to me? Do you have to do anything to PulseAudio to make it let you monitor its stream? Should I actually be trying to instead connect to a sink to monitor what's being played?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to check the sources with e.g.:

```
pacmd list-sources | grep -e device.string -e 'name:'
```

and then connct to the source ending on ".monitor" by using the "device" property of pulsesrc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I tried that and failed, likely because I don't know how to use the "device" property of pulsesrc. I assume through a GstElement but what's the call?